# Why can't i register more than 2 hosted services in a single Windows Service application in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, .net-5

I have a Windows Service application written using .NET 5 platform. Here's my Main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) =>
    Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
        {
             var configuration = services
                 .BuildServiceProvider()
                 .GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

             services
                 .AddApplicationServices()
                 .AddInfrastructureServices(configuration);
        })
        .UseWindowsService()
        .Build()
        .Run();
```

I have few services in the application registered with the following method:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCronJob<TJob>(this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    string cronExpressionSectionKey,
    string triggerOnStartupSectionKey = default) where TJob : CronJobService
{
    var cronExpression = configuration.GetSection(cronExpressionSectionKey).Value;
    var missingCronExpression = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cronExpressionSectionKey) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cronExpression);

    if (missingCronExpression)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(EmptyCronExpressionMessage);
    }
    
    var triggerOnStartup = bool.TryParse(configuration.GetSection(triggerOnStartupSectionKey).Value,
        out var parsingResult) && parsingResult;

    var config = new ScheduleConfig<TJob>
    {
        CronExpression = cronExpression,
        TimeZoneLocal = TimeZoneInfo.Local,
        TimeZoneUtc = TimeZoneInfo.Utc,
        TriggerOnStartup = triggerOnStartup
    };

    return services
        .AddSingleton<IScheduleConfig<TJob>>(config)
        .AddHostedService<TJob>(); 
}
```

The registration looks like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services
        .AddDatabaseContext<ExchangeContext>(
            configuration,
            DatabaseProvider.SqlServer,
            false,
            ExchangeConnectionStringSectionKey,
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)
        .AddDomesticMessaging(GetHandlersAssembly())
        .AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>()
        .AddScoped<IImportMetadataRepository, ImportMetadataRepository>()
        .AddScoped<IFetchedStockPriceRepository, FetchedStockPriceRepository>()
        .AddScoped<IPredictionModelRepository, PredictionModelRepository>()
        .AddScoped<ITimeSeriesPort, TimeSeriesAdaptor>()
        .AddScoped<IPredictionModelPort, PredictionModelAdaptor>()
        .AddScoped<IPredictorPort, PredictorAdaptor>()
        .AddCronJob<ExchangeDataImportService>(
            configuration,
            ExchangeDataImportServiceCronExpressionSectionKey,
            ExchangeDataImportServiceTriggerOnStartupSectionKey)
        .AddCronJob<PredictionModelService>(
            configuration,
            PredictionModelServiceCronExpressionSectionKey,
            PredictionModelServiceTriggerOnStartupSectionKey)
        .AddCronJob<PredictionService>(
            configuration,
            PredictionServiceCronExpressionSectionKey,
            PredictionServiceTriggerOnStartupSectionKey)
        .Configure<TimeSeriesSourceSettings>(configuration.GetSection(TimeSeriesSourceSettingsSectionKey))
        .Configure<PredictionModelSettings>(configuration.GetSection(PredictionModelSettingsSectionKey));

    var migrator = new Migrator(services);
    migrator.UseMigrationsOfContext<ExchangeContext>();

    return services;
}
```

The AddCronJob mechanism was tested many many times in my projects - it works perfectly and my problem is for sure not connected with the working principle of given method. Please notice that it encapsulates AddHostedService method. Let's move to the main obstacle. This is the first time i've tried to have more than one cron job in one Windows Service. Everything works correctly, until i register the third service. Services derive from BackgroundService class (they also need to override ExecuteAsync method). When random services are registered, ExecuteAsync method is called properly, but when i add the third one - his method is never called (don't know why).
The last registered service is invalid - when i change the order of the registration, the other service stops working. What am i doing wrong? Are there any limitations with the AddHostedService method? Thanks for any answer.

PredictionService definition:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AsCore.Application.Abstractions.Messaging.Commands;
using AsCore.Infrastructure.Workers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SharePricePredictor.Application.Contracts.Commands;

namespace SharePricePredictor.Infrastructure.Workers
{
    public sealed class PredictionService : CronJobService
    {
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        public PredictionService(IScheduleConfig<PredictionService> scheduleConfig,
            IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
                : base(
                    scheduleConfig.CronExpression,
                    scheduleConfig.TimeZoneLocal,
                    scheduleConfig.TimeZoneUtc,
                    scheduleConfig.TriggerOnStartup) =>
                        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var commandBus = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICommandBus>();
            var command = new PredictCommand();
            
            await commandBus.SendAsync(command, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

PredictionModelService definition:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AsCore.Application.Abstractions.Messaging.Commands;
using AsCore.Infrastructure.Workers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SharePricePredictor.Application.Contracts.Commands;

namespace SharePricePredictor.Infrastructure.Workers
{
    public sealed class PredictionModelService : CronJobService
    {
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

        public PredictionModelService(
            IScheduleConfig<PredictionModelService> scheduleConfig,
            IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
                : base(scheduleConfig.CronExpression,
                    scheduleConfig.TimeZoneLocal,
                    scheduleConfig.TimeZoneUtc,
                    scheduleConfig.TriggerOnStartup)
        {
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var commandBus = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICommandBus>();
            var command = new CreatePredictionModelCommand();

            await commandBus.SendAsync(command, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add code for the not working service and the service registered before it (`PredictionModelService` and `PredictionService` as far as i understand).

Comment: @GuruStron i've attached the services code :) Thanks for your interest, regards